# Echoing multiple rows of a database query with php

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an accordion (twitter bootstrap) displaying all of someone's friends, I end up just creating a infinate loop, basically all I am trying to do is echoing out a php string for each line in the results.

can anyone spot what I am doing stupid (other than not using mysqli)?

```
    while ( $rowresult = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE id='".$user["ID"]."' ")) ) {
        $auto = "0px";
        echo '<div class="accordion-group"><div class="accordion-heading"><div class="accordion-heading">';
        echo '<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse'. $counter . '">';       
        echo $rowresult['firstname'];
        echo ' ';
        echo $rowresult['lastname'];
        echo ', ';
        echo $rowresult['headline'];
        echo '</a></div> <div id="collapse'. $counter .'" class="accordion-body ';
        if ($counter == 0){
        echo 'in ';
        $auto = "auto";
        }
        echo 'collapse" style="height: '. $auto .'; "><div class="accordion-inner">';
        echo '<img src="'.$rowresult["pictureUrl"].'">';        
        echo '</div></div></div></div>';    
        $counter++;
    }
```

Comment: `mysql_` functions have begun to be deprecated. [Read this](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you are executing the same query again and again.
Do that instead:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE id='".$user["ID"]."'");
while ( $rowresult = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
....
}
```

Also, I suggest you use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 1):

You are repeating your query on every iteration. Move the mysql_query() out of the loop to a variable.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE id='".$user["ID"]."' ");
while ($rowresult = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the query before the while loop. IE

```
 $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE id='".$user["ID"]."' ");
 while ( $rowresult = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
```

...

But then of course use PDO... :)